# three.js library for windows 8 metro app

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, three.js

how to use three.js library 
to make a windows 8 metro app

i tried to use it but app suddenly stops working
just after showing splash screen

may be there is some issue with object
`THREE.WebGLRenderer()`

is there anyfix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `CanvasRenderer` or `CSS3DRenderer`.
Download the repo and check the `canvas_*` in the examples folder.

Comment: CanvasRenderer is working but why others are not?
and when i use CanvasRenderer objects are blinking ,any fix?